# Handle 500 internal server error while sending SMS using twilio in PHP

Tags: php, android, magento, twilio

I am using Twilio sdk to send SMS in my PHP based application,I have an array of phone numbers and sending an SMS to each number in this array in a loop.....the problem is while the loop is running if an invalid number comes twilio API returns **500 internal server error** and it stops the loop without trying sending sms for rest of the numbers in the array.

This is the code I am using for sending sms :

```
public function sendSmsAction($userphones)
{   
 foreach($userphones as $user_phone)
 {
  $message = 'Thanks for coming';
  $this->twiliosms($user_phone,$message);
 }
}

private function twiliosms($phone_num,$message)
{
    require Mage::getBaseDir()."/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php";
    $AccountSid = "XXXXXXX";
    $AuthToken = "XXXXXXX";
   $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
    try {
         $message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
         "From" => "+1XXXXXXXXXX",
         "To" => $phone_num,
         "Body" => $message,
         ));
        } catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting :

**Status: 500 Internal Server Error**

**The 'To' number +1XXXXXXXXXX is not a valid phone number or shortcode.**

please help me out in handling this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Validate your phone numbers before sending to Twilio.

Comment: ok.But I didn't found such function call in twilio documents.Can you pls give me reference url or url for that API call???

Comment: >> it stops the loop << don't see a loop

Comment: It isn't an API call, you have to write something yourself.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It is an API and I am using Twilio PHP SDK...and here in code I am creating an object of that twilio API sdk class, look the line containing
    Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

Comment: I know it is an API. I am just saying that you can validate the numbers before you send them to the API. IIRC the API has no method for validating the numbers.

Comment: @donald123 the above given code runs in a loop.

Comment: Hi Piyush, could you include the full code you are running, including the loop, please.

Comment: ok.I am going to update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got my solution....by just adding another catch()  made it working fine...

```
catch(Exception $e)
{

}
```